# Error trying to build a executable spring boot jar

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

I'm just trying to build a executable jar using Spring Boot, based on Joel example https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/spring-observable-stream, but I'm getting the following error:

```
exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.config.ActiveMQDefaultConfiguration.getDefaultRoutingType()Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/RoutingType;
```

at this line of code:

```
CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress).start(username, password)
```

Obs.: Invoking via JavaExec task it works perfectly.

Comment: Hey Maka, what command are you using to build the executable JAR?

Comment: Hi Joel, I've just put the bootRepackage task:  

`bootRepackage{ mainClass = "namespace.mainClass" executable = true }`

and then `gradlew build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a jar issue. which doesn't have this method. This method has been moved around look for this jar having package name as: org.apache.activemq.artemis. in client and common. not sure here but that's the culprit for you either go for version 1.X or 2.X just check which one has this method.
force compile to version 2.X for both client and common in your gradle file you will be good to go.

Comment: Exactly. The problem was the artemis-core-client jar. Just forced to 2.X and it worked as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the following to my `build.gradle` file's `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {

    ...

    compile "org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:2.0.0"
    compile "org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:2.0.0"

    ...

}
```